# Processing multiple results from CLR stored procedure in T-SQL

Tags: c#, sql-server, performance, stored-procedures, sqlclr

I have some complex algorithm written in C# as CLR Stored procedure. Procedure is not deterministic (it depends on current time). The result of procedure are two tables.
I didn't found any solution how to process multi-results from stored procedures in T-SQL. The performance of this procedure is key (procedure is called every ~2 seconds).

I found the fastest way how to update tables is:

```
UPDATE [db-table] SET ... SELECT * FROM [clr-func]
```

It's much faster then update db-table from CLR procedure via ADO.NET.

I used static field to store results and query it after the execution of clr stored procedure.

The call stack is:

```
T-SQL proc
    -> CLR proc (MyStoredProcedure)
        -> T-SQL proc (UpdateDataFromMyStoredProcedure)
            -> CLR func (GetFirstResultOfMyStoredProcedure)
            -> CLR func (GetSecondResultOfMyStoredProcedure)
```

The problem is, sometimes CLR functions has null in static field `result`, but in CLR procedure is `result` not null. I found, sometimes the CLR functions are called in another AppDomain than CLR procedure. However CLR procedure is still running and can do next operations and no exception is thrown.

Is there some way, how to force CLR functions to be called in same AppDomain as "parent" CLR procedure?

Or is there some another way, how to achieve my intention?

P.S.: Originally the complex algorithm was written in T-SQL, but performance was poor (~100x slower than algorithm in C#).

Thanks!

Simplified code:

```
// T-SQL
CREATE PROC [dbo].[UpdateDataFromMyStoredProcedure] AS BEGIN
    UPDATE [dbo].[tblObject]
        SET ...
        SELECT * FROM [dbo].[GetFirstResultOfMyStoredProcedure]()
    UPDATE [dbo].[tblObjectAction]
        SET ...
        SELECT * FROM [dbo].[GetSecondResultOfMyStoredProcedure]()
END

// ... somewhere else
EXEC [dbo].[MyStoredProcedure]
```

-

```
// C#
public class StoredProcedures {
    // store for result of "MyStoredProcedure ()"
    private static MyStoredProcedureResult result;
    [SqlProcedure]
    public static int MyStoredProcedure() {
        result = null;
        result = ComputeComplexAlgorithm();
        UpdateDataFromMyStoredProcedure();
        result = null;
    }
    [SqlFunction(...)]
    public static IEnumerable GetFirstResultOfMyStoredProcedure() {
        return result.First;
    }
    [SqlFunction(...)]
    public static IEnumerable GetSecondResultOfMyStoredProcedure() {
        return result.Second;
    }
    private static void UpdateDataFromMyStoredProcedure() {
        using(var cnn = new SqlConnection("context connection=true")) {
            using(var cmd = cnn.CreateCommand()) {
                cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.CommandText = "[dbo].[UpdateDataFromMyStoredProcedure]";
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe it would make sense to implement [dbo].[UpdateDataFromMyStoredProcedure] in CLR as well?

Comment: @Piotr Rodak: For update db-table from CLR proc I know only one way: using SqlCommand and call update for every record. It's very slow in comparision with classic T-SQL UPDATE - and I need process it very fast :(.

Answer (score 3):

There are two possibilities:

- The more likely scenario has to do with App Domains getting unloaded due to memory pressure. Generally speaking, there is only a single App Domain for a particular Assembly (and hence for the code in it) since App Domains are per-Database, per-Owner. So your code is not being called in two App Domains, *at least not conceptually*.

  However, there is a particular sequence-of-events nuance to how SQL Server handles unloading App Domains that you are experiencing. What is happening is that your system is experiencing memory pressure and is marking the App Domain to be unloaded. This can be seen in the SQL Server logs as it will tell you the exact name of the App Domain that is being unloaded.

  > AppDomain 61 ({database_name}.{owner_name}[runtime].60) is marked for unload due to memory pressure.

  When an App Domain is marked for unload, it is allowed to continue running until all currently running process complete. At this point it has a "state" of `E_APPDOMAIN_DOOMED` instead of the normal `E_APPDOMAIN_SHARED`. If another process is started, *even from within the doomed App Domain*, a new App Domain is created. And this is what causes the behavior you are experiencing. The sequence of events is as follows (and yes, I have reproduced this behavior):

  1. Execute `MyStoredProcedure`: App Domain 1 is created if not already existing. App Domain 1 "state" is `E_APPDOMAIN_SHARED`. `result` is set to `null`.

     1. `result` is populated as expected
     2. `MyStoredProcedure` executes `GetFirstResultOfMyStoredProcedure`: App Domain 1 "state" is still `E_APPDOMAIN_SHARED`. `result` is retrieved as expected.
     3. App Domain 1 is marked for unload: App Domain 1 "state" is changed to `E_APPDOMAIN_DOOMED`
     4. `MyStoredProcedure` executes `GetSecondResultOfMyStoredProcedure`: App Domain 1 "state" is still `E_APPDOMAIN_DOOMED` and so cannot be used. App Domain 2 is created. App Domain 2 "state" is `E_APPDOMAIN_SHARED`. `result` is set to `null`. This is why you sometimes get nothing back: this process is in App Domain 2 (even though it was initiated from App Domain 1), with no access to App Domain 1.
  2. `MyStoredProcedure` completes: App Domain 1 is unloaded.

  And there is another possibility of how this sequence of events could occur:  App Domain 1 could be marked for unload prior to executing `GetFirstResultOfMyStoredProcedure`. In this case, App Domain 2 is created when `GetFirstResultOfMyStoredProcedure` is executed, and both it and `GetSecondResultOfMyStoredProcedure` run in App Domain 2 and return nothing.

  Hence, if you want / need an error to be thrown under these conditions, then your `Get*ResultOfMyStoredProcedure` methods need to check if `result == null` before attempting to retrieve, and if it is null, then throw an error. OR, if it is possible to recalculate the value of what is being stored in the static variable, then if it is `null` simply repopulate it (e.g. call `ComputeComplexAlgorithm` again).
- A less likely possibility is that since the App Domain is shared by all sessions / callers to that code, it is *possible*, if you have not otherwise ensured that there is only ever 1 execution of this process at a time, that someone else or a SQL Agent job or something, executed `MyStoredProcedure` which would null out the static variable as it starts.

  Since you have already accepted using an `UNSAFE` Assembly in order to get the updateable static variable, you might as well add a locking mechanism to ensure that `MyStoredProcedure` is single-threaded.

---

Aside from those areas to look at, this process could most likely be done even faster and in a less convoluted manner. You can use Table-Valued Parameters (TVPs) to stream data back to SQL Server, just like you would from app code. Just create one or two User-Defined Table Types (UDTTs) that match the structures of the two result sets being returned by the TVFs (`GetFirstResultOfMyStoredProcedure` and `GetSecondResultOfMyStoredProcedure`). Please see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19957132/pass-dictionarystring-int-to-stored-procedure-t-sql/25815939#25815939) regarding how to properly stream in the results. By using this model, you can:

- do both updates inline in the `MyStoredProcedure` CLR proc
- get rid of the static variable
- Possibly no more need for `UNSAFE` (if it was only being used for the static variable). You might still need `EXTERNAL_ACCESS` if you can't pass back the results over the Context Connection, in which case you would use a regular connection (i.e. connection string uses either "Server=(local)" or doesn't specify "Server").
- get rid of `UpdateDataFromMyStoredProcedure` method
- get rid of `UpdateDataFromMyStoredProcedure` T-SQL proc
- get rid of `GetFirstResultOfMyStoredProcedure` CLR function
- get rid of `GetSecondResultOfMyStoredProcedure` CLR function
- free up all of the memory that is currently being used by that static variable to hold two result sets!!

Not only is this approach easier to maintain and most likely faster, it also does not allow for the new App Domain with uninitialized static variable issue that you are running into here :-).

Comment: Thanks for update. We solved that by storing data in external process.

Comment: No problem :). If you don't mind, would you please elaborate, at least a little, on how you stored the data in another process? Thanks.

Comment: It was supersimple. It was just static dictionaries.

Answer (score 2):

According to [Bob Beauchemin](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/bobb/post/SQLCLR-appdomain-usage.aspx) "SQLCLR creates one appdomain per assembly owner, not one appdomain per database"
Do both your SQLCLR Assemblies have the same owner?

Comment: CLR procedure and CLR functions are in the same class. So yes, they are in same assembly. But mainly - it works fine. Only sometimes (once per ~(1x - 20x) runs) the issue occures.