# Pass Dictionary<string,int> to Stored Procedure T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, t-sql, import

I have mvc application. In action I have `Dictionary<string,int>`. The `Key` is ID and `Value` is sortOrderNumber. I want to create stored procedure that will be get key(id) find this record in database and save `orderNumber` column by `value` from Dictionary. I want to call stored procedure once time and pass data to it, instead of calling many times for updating data.

Have you any ideas?
Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Using Table Valued parameters is really not that complex.

given this SQL:

```
CREATE TYPE MyTableType as TABLE (ID nvarchar(25),OrderNumber int) 


CREATE PROCEDURE MyTableProc (@myTable MyTableType READONLY)    
   AS
   BEGIN
    SELECT * from @myTable
   END
```

this will show how relatively easy it is, it just selects out the values you sent in for demo purposes. I am sure you can easily abstract this away in your case.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace TVPSample
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //setup some data
            var dict = new Dictionary<string, int>();
            for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++)
            {
                dict.Add(x.ToString(),x+100);
            }
            //convert to DataTable
            var dt = ConvertToDataTable(dict);
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("[Your Connection String here]"))
            {
                conn.Open();
                using (SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("MyTableProc",conn))
                {
                    comm.CommandType=CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    var param = comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("myTable", dt);
                    //this is the most important part:
                    param.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;
                    var reader = comm.ExecuteReader(); //or NonQuery, etc.
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", reader["ID"], reader["OrderNumber"]);
                    }

                }
            }
        }

        //I am sure there is a more elegant way of doing this.
        private static DataTable ConvertToDataTable(Dictionary<string, int> dict)
        {
            var dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("ID",typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("OrderNumber", typeof(Int32));
            foreach (var pair in dict)
            {
                var row = dt.NewRow();
                row["ID"] = pair.Key;
                row["OrderNumber"] = pair.Value;
                dt.Rows.Add(row);
            }
            return dt;
        }
    }
}
```

Produces

```
0 100
1 101
2 102
3 103
4 104
5 105
6 106
7 107
8 108
9 109
```

Comment: If a lot of data is being passed in, then it would be more efficient to stream the data in via the IEnumerable interface as opposed to making a 2nd copy of the original data in the form of a DataTable. I wrote an article about this method including a working example here: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/SQL+Server+2008/66554/

Comment: @srutzky - that's a really good article! Would you consider putting a a sample up as an answer here?

Comment: Why do we have to create a DataTable? Why cannot we pass the dictionary directly?

Comment: @Aref - I guess you'd have to take that up with the authors of System.Data :) Perhaps future versions of SQL Server will have tighter integration with .NET, who knows...

Comment: @Aref: You don't _need_ to create a DataTable. I just posted an answer (as Stephen had requested of me in a comment above) that shows a fully streamed structure: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19957132/pass-dictionarystring-int-to-stored-procedure-t-sql/25815939#25815939 . There are 3 types that can be sent as TVP: `DataTable`, `DbDataReader`, and `IEnumerable<SqlDataRecord>`. One thing they all have in common is that they contain the SqlMetaData to define the structure in terms of T-SQL. My example shows the closest thing to passing a `Dictionary` directly.

Answer (score 23):

The accepted answer of using a TVP is generally correct, but needs some clarification based on the amount of data being passed in. Using a DataTable is fine (not to mention quick and easy) for smaller sets of data, but for larger sets it does not scale given that it duplicates the dataset by placing it in the DataTable simply for the means of passing it to SQL Server. So, for larger sets of data there is an option to stream the contents of any custom collection. The only real requirement is that you need to define the structure in terms of SqlDb types and iterate through the collection, both of which are fairly trivial steps.

A simplistic overview of the minimal structure is shown below, which is an adaptation of the answer I posted on [How can I insert 10 million records in the shortest time possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25770180/how-i-can-insert-10-million-entry-in-shortest-time-possible/25773471#25773471), which deals with importing data from a file and is hence slightly different as the data is not currently in memory. As you can see from the code below, this setup is not overly complicated yet highly flexible as well as efficient and scalable.

**SQL object # 1: Define the structure**

```sql
-- First: You need a User-Defined Table Type
CREATE TYPE dbo.IDsAndOrderNumbers AS TABLE
(
   ID NVARCHAR(4000) NOT NULL,
   SortOrderNumber INT NOT NULL
);
GO
```

**SQL object # 2: Use the structure**

```sql
-- Second: Use the UDTT as an input param to an import proc.
--         Hence "Tabled-Valued Parameter" (TVP)
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.ImportData (
   @ImportTable    dbo.IDsAndOrderNumbers READONLY
)
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON;

-- maybe clear out the table first?
TRUNCATE TABLE SchemaName.TableName;

INSERT INTO SchemaName.TableName (ID, SortOrderNumber)
    SELECT  tmp.ID,
            tmp.SortOrderNumber
    FROM    @ImportTable tmp;

-- OR --

some other T-SQL

-- optional return data
SELECT @NumUpdates AS [RowsUpdated],
       @NumInserts AS [RowsInserted];
GO
```

**C# code, Part 1: Define the iterator/sender**

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Server;

private static IEnumerable<SqlDataRecord> SendRows(Dictionary<string,int> RowData)
{
   SqlMetaData[] _TvpSchema = new SqlMetaData[] {
      new SqlMetaData("ID", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 4000),
      new SqlMetaData("SortOrderNumber", SqlDbType.Int)
   };
   SqlDataRecord _DataRecord = new SqlDataRecord(_TvpSchema);
   StreamReader _FileReader = null;

      // read a row, send a row
      foreach (KeyValuePair<string,int> _CurrentRow in RowData)
      {
         // You shouldn't need to call "_DataRecord = new SqlDataRecord" as
         // SQL Server already received the row when "yield return" was called.
         // Unlike BCP and BULK INSERT, you have the option here to create an
         // object, do manipulation(s) / validation(s) on the object, then pass
         // the object to the DB or discard via "continue" if invalid.
         _DataRecord.SetString(0, _CurrentRow.ID);
         _DataRecord.SetInt32(1, _CurrentRow.sortOrderNumber);

         yield return _DataRecord;
      }
}
```

**C# code, Part 2: Use the iterator/sender**

```cs
public static void LoadData(Dictionary<string,int> MyCollection)
{
   SqlConnection _Connection = new SqlConnection("{connection string}");
   SqlCommand _Command = new SqlCommand("ImportData", _Connection);
   SqlDataReader _Reader = null; // only needed if getting data back from proc call

   SqlParameter _TVParam = new SqlParameter();
   _TVParam.ParameterName = "@ImportTable";
// _TVParam.TypeName = "IDsAndOrderNumbers"; //optional for CommandType.StoredProcedure
   _TVParam.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;
   _TVParam.Value = SendRows(MyCollection); // method return value is streamed data
   _Command.Parameters.Add(_TVParam);
   _Command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

   try
   {
      _Connection.Open();

      // Either send the data and move on with life:
      _Command.ExecuteNonQuery();
      // OR, to get data back from a SELECT or OUTPUT clause:
      SqlDataReader _Reader = _Command.ExecuteReader();
      {
       Do something with _Reader: If using INSERT or MERGE in the Stored Proc, use an
       OUTPUT clause to return INSERTED.[RowNum], INSERTED.[ID] (where [RowNum] is an
       IDENTITY), then fill a new Dictionary<string, int>(ID, RowNumber) from
       _Reader.GetString(0) and _Reader.GetInt32(1). Return that instead of void.
      }
   }
   finally
   {
      _Reader.Dispose(); // optional; needed if getting data back from proc call
      _Command.Dispose();
      _Connection.Dispose();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Stored procedures do not support arrays as inputs. Googling gives a couple of hacks using XML or comma separated strings, but those are hacks.

A more SQLish way to do this is to create a temporary table (named e.g. `#Orders`) and insert all the data into that one. Then you can call the sp, using *the same open Sql Connection* and insie the SP use the `#Orders` table to read the values.

Another solution is to use [Table-Valued Parameters](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx) but that requires some more SQL to setup so I think it is probably easier to use the temp table approach.

Comment: Well, they do: "table valued parameters" - it just isn't trivial

Comment: @MarcGravell Yes, you're right - I added that as an edit while you commented. To me, the temp table approach looks easier - which one do you prefer?

Comment: Also note they support table valued parameters only from SqlServer2008

Comment: -1 I try to not down-vote but this is bad advice and the up-votes show that others are unaware of this. 1) XML is a valid, flexible way to pass a multidimensional array. I have used XML many times with much success in throughput and ease of refactoring (not a hack). 2) sending a CSV list for a simple list of numbers to split in the proc into a temp table is very fast and minimal code (not a hack). 3) TVPs are the most efficient way of sending arrays in a strongly typed _and_ streamed manner. The only SQL setup is a 1-time CREATE TYPE statement. Many INSERTs is slower than all of these options.