# Sending multiple parameters from Asp.Net to my stored procedure in SQL Server

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I have a list box in Asp.Net from where the user selects one or multiple parameters and send it to a stored procedure. The selected of number of parameters depends completely on the user so I don't know how many parameters the user is going to choose from the list box. I also want to retrieve data back from the table with those parameters when I click on the Submit button and display on a gridview. The issue I am having is I can send one parameter and retrieve data back from my stored procedure but I really don't know how to send multiple parameters from the list box to my stored procedure.

Below is the code for single parameter in Asp.Net

```
protected void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string s = "Submit";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(s, con);

    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = lbCT.SelectedItem.Value;

    con.Open();

    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds);

    gvDS.DataSource = ds; 
    gvDS.DataBind();

    con.Close();
}
```

Below is my stored procedure in SQL Server

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [Submit]
    @Name VARCHAR(12)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT *
    FROM Employee 
    WHERE Name = @Name
END
```

Comment: Look into table valued parameters. Sounds like that is exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: Other tips: `SqlCommand` and `SqlDataAdapter` are both `IDisposable` so should be in `using` blocks. And so is the `SqlConnection`, so you may want to consider changing that to being a local variable as well (if you do that, you won't need the `con.Close()`).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pass Dictionary<string,int> to Stored Procedure T-SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19957132/pass-dictionarystring-int-to-stored-procedure-t-sql)

Answer (score 0):

You are sending just parameter and using equals "=" operator. Instead of this, you should send all selected items and split your parameter by delimiter.

Please follow these steps:

1.Create a new sql function for split name/names

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.splitstring (@stringToSplit VARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS
 @returnList TABLE ([Name] [nvarchar] (500))
AS
BEGIN

 DECLARE @name NVARCHAR(255)
 DECLARE @pos INT

 WHILE CHARINDEX(',', @stringToSplit) > 0
 BEGIN
  SELECT @pos  = CHARINDEX(',', @stringToSplit)  
  SELECT @name = SUBSTRING(@stringToSplit, 1, @pos-1)

  INSERT INTO @returnList 
  SELECT @name

  SELECT @stringToSplit = SUBSTRING(@stringToSplit, @pos+1, LEN(@stringToSplit)-@pos)
 END

 INSERT INTO @returnList
 SELECT @stringToSplit

 RETURN
END
```

2.Update your procedure

> WHERE Name in (Select dbo.splitstring (@Names))

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [Submit]
    @Names VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT *
    FROM Employee 
    WHERE Name in (Select dbo.splitstring (@Names))
END
```

3.Update your Codebehind parameter

> cmd.Parameters.Add("@Names", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = join all
>   selected items with ','

```
protected void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string s = "Submit";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(s, con);

    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Names", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = /*join all selected items with ','*/

    con.Open();

    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds);

    gvDS.DataSource = ds; 
    gvDS.DataBind();

    con.Close();
}
```